# YARD::Handlers::Ruby::AttributeHandler: Undocumentable warning

Tags: ruby, yard

I'm new to Yard, but have taken on maintenance of a project which uses it. When I run `rake yard` it succeeds but emits a warning:

```
[warn]: in YARD::Handlers::Ruby::AttributeHandler: Undocumentable Configuration::VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS
    in file 'lib/pocket/api.rb':7:

    7: attr_accessor(*Configuration::VALID_OPTIONS_KEYS)
```

The repo is at https://github.com/turadg/pocket-ruby

I've looked at Yard's documentation and I understand this may be related to the use of the splat operator (*) but I'm unsure how to eliminate the warning. Any advice?

Ruby 3.0.1, Yard 0.9.26

Comment: What Ruby and Yard versions are you working with?

Comment: Added to my original post.